# How can I get Lord of Hollows ending?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I'm stuck at the end of the game. Beware, **spoiler alert**.

I just defeated Soul of Cinders boss and when I went to the First flame, I saw a mark to summon the Fire keeper, so I did that, thinking she will ask me what to do with the flame. Well, she doesn't, and trigger the end "The end of fire".

Now, I'm still in this run (I didn't rerun the game as NG+) because I wanted Lord of hollows ending.

**But when I come back to the Firelink Shrine, Yuria is still there, telling me to steal the first flame.**

Is it possible? How to do that? Or is it just the speech not updated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you've failed Lord of Hollows ending in this walkthrough.

> To achieve it you have to use the bonfire itself, not summon sign.

Also, double check requirements for it - you should have 8 [Dark Sigils](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Dark+Sigil).

Comment: Yes I had the 8 dark sigils... Damn, I'll do it in NG+